# BATCH: goto EOF if name contains partial word

Tags: batch-file, contains, eof, goto

i have a batch script and it has a variable '%4' and is random file names but sometimes it has names like:

> 030813.mp3
>   20130307.mp3

and i want to have it goto EOF if the ext is mp3

i have this so far but it's not working

> IF %4==*.mp3 GOTO EOF

Answer (score 3, accepted):

%~x4 expands %4 to a file extension
 ( http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/percent.mspx?mfr=true )
 ... so try `IF %~x4==.mp3 GOTO EOF`

Comment: Adding `/I` and including quotes will make that case-insensitive (match .mp3 as well as .MP3) and will handle files with no extension: `IF /I "%~x4"==".mp3" GOTO EOF`

Comment: that's working perfectly thank you Mr Fuzzy Button and thank you also Nate Hekman for the tip :)